Facebook JS SDK not returning Email address
This looks like a common issue, although I've spent an entire day on it and cannot get the Facebook JS SDK to return my email. I've set my email address visibility to public, unlocked my profile and my email address is also verified.
No matter what I do I only get the ID, first name and last name... if I add birthday or most other fields, that works; but no email address.
When I look at the App in my Facebook profile, I can see it has the email permission. Remove it and add it again and no change. Any suggestions on my code below would be greatly appreciated?! Thank you.
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>

<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId : "myAppIDIsHere",
        cookie : true,
        xfbml : true,
        version : "v19.0"
    });

    FB.login (function (fbResponse) {
        console.log (fbResponse);
        if (fbResponse.authResponse) {
            accessToken = fbResponse.authResponse.accessToken;
            FB.api ('/me', { fields: 'email,first_name,last_name' }, function (fbResponse2) {
                console.log (fbResponse2);
            });
        }
    }, { scope: 'email,public_profile' });
});
</script>


The code looks alright, there is nothing to change about it that could make it work any "better." Facebook themselves have stated in the past, that even with all the known requirements fulfilled, there might still be some edge cases in which you won't get an email address, perhaps it is one of those cases. Maybe try adding a new, additional email to your profile, and then try and go through the hole process (beginning with granting the permissions to your app) again.

I don't know what happens when publishing the app as I haven't done that yet, but, I could get the email in response after I did this during development and get the email:

Click here


Open the graph api explorer:


Add the permission and add the field name. If you wanna test this from the Graph api itself, then you gotta hit Generate Access Token


In the code add this: FB.api("/me", { fields: "id,name,email" }, funct...

Restart the FE app after you made these changes and make sure the script has reloaded.


and I could see the email in the returned response. Again, I haven't published the app yet, it seems to require business verification procedures as well. I may update the post later, but not sure how difficult that procedure is. Hope this helps.

We have a verified business and went through the publishing logic, only to find that at some stage in mid 2024 the email stopped being returned. No matter what I do in the graph api explorer I will never get the email returned.
